# Content not loading and logging with delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm doing a `React` project for my bootcamp and I'm passing a `details` array as a `descripcion` props from my `ItemDetailContainer` component to my `ItemDetail` component. When I try to console.log my `descripcion` props in `ItemDetail`, it first logs an empty array and after a few seconds it logs the actual array with my product's details.

The problem is that the `ItemDetails` component is not rendering the data from the array but I can log its content.

I thought this was caused do to the setTimeOut function or UseEffect hook in my code but I still get this problem when I remove them

My `ItemDetailContainer` code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Product from "../../product.json";
import ItemDetail from "./ItemDetail";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ItemDetailContainer = () => {

    const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
    
    const getItem = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(Product)
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    
    useEffect(() => { 
        getItem().then(setDetails)
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="producto-descripcion">
                <ItemDetail descripcion={details}></ItemDetail>
            </div>

            <button class="back-shopping"><Link className="route-link" to="/category/:id">go back to shopping</Link></button>
        </>
    )
}

export default `ItemDetailContainer`
```

My ItemDetail code:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router"

const ItemDetail = ({descripcion}) => {

    console.log(descripcion)
    const { id } = useParams();

    return (
        <>
            <div className="produc-desc" id={id}>
                {descripcion.filter(desc => desc.id === id).map((desc, index) => (
                    <div key={index}className="full-card">
                        <h2>{desc.name}</h2>
                        <img src={desc.pictureURL} alt="unisex hoodie" id="picture-store"/>
                        <p>{desc.price}</p>
                        <h4 id="texto-descripcion">{desc.description}</h4>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ItemDetail
```

The output of the console.log in the `ItemDetail` component:

```
Array(0)
```

and then:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: 'PHONE CASE', stock: '17', price: '$9.99', pictureURL: 'https://www.montblanc.com/variants/images/19971654706771425/A/w2500.jpg', …}
1: {id: 2, name: 'PINK HOODIE', stock: '12', price: '$24.99', pictureURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0040/6146/2626/p…87992ClLogoHoodiepinkfront_1200x.png?v=1628299298', …}
2: {id: 3, name: 'WHITE SHIRT', stock: '23', price: '$14.99', pictureURL: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/vader-prod.s3.amazonaw…m/1623333444-61jgr5y0ibl-ac-ul1500-1623333437.jpg', …}
3: {id: 4, name: 'BLACK HOODIE', stock: '9', price: '$24.99', pictureURL: 'https://ninefoldpath.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/NINE-BEATS-Logo-hoodie-600x600.jpg', …}
length: 4
```

What am I missing? Let me know if I wasnt clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you log the `id` that return by `useParams`?

Comment: @PeterlitsZo Yes! Also it logs 2 times succesfully, during both of the renders of my page. Unlike the `descripcion` props which first logs an empty array on the first render and then it logs the `details` elements of the array

Answer (score 0):

The first time react renders the details state is `[]` therefore the first time it renders you see `Array(0)` in the console, and right after you see the desired array values, that is normal and expected React behaviour.

What you can do is something like this:

```js
const ItemDetail = ({descripcion}) => {

    console.log(descripcion)
    const { id } = useParams();

    return (
        {
        (description.length > 0) ?
            <div className="produc-desc" id={id}>
                {descripcion.filter(desc => desc.id === id).map((desc, index) => (
                    <div key={index}className="full-card">
                        <h2>{desc.name}</h2>
                        <img src={desc.pictureURL} alt="unisex hoodie" id="picture-store"/>
                        <p>{desc.price}</p>
                        <h4 id="texto-descripcion">{desc.description}</h4>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        : <div>Getting data</div>
        }
    )
}

export default ItemDetail
```

So you render a different message, in this case "Getting data" and as soon as the state changes you render the desired JSX, hope that makes sense.

There are many different ways to tackle this, I'm just giving you a simple workaround, you may want to check [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) that will help you take more control over your component render lifecycles.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, basically the filter was comparing the useParams id which is a string to an integer id. Solved with a `toString()` like this:
Before  `desc.id === id` after `desc.id.toString() === id`

Comment: I thought the problem was due to the delay on the rendering phase, not the fact that there was no content displayed from the array, as a side not you can destructure `descripcion.filter({id, name, price, description} => id === id)` to this `descripcion.filter(desc => desc.id === id)` and saves you from using `desc.` for every item